# Disallowing Backslashes in a Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, regex, backslash

For a Username field there are certain varaitions that cannot be chosen as an appropiate username nor can certain characters be used.

For example: TIM1....TIM9 cannot be used BIN1....BIN9 cannot be used, nor can the characters `<>:\/|?*` appear anywhere in the field.

The code I have so far is thus:

```
    private bool ValidateId(string regexValue)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("TIM[1-9]|BIN[1-9]|[<>:\"/|?*]");
        return !regex.IsMatch(regexValue);
    }
```

What I'm struggling to allow for however is the backslash character. Trying to escape it as I have done with the quotation character doesn't appear to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To *allow* for? Meaning the backslash is a valid character?

Comment: What backslash character? Can you show what the regex is supposed to look like without any C#-string-escape messing it?

Comment: It always a better idea to validate for what you want, not what you don't want.

Comment: @Stargazer712: Dialect thing - when I said allow for what I meant was take into account, render it invalid a la the other characters.

Comment: @Jason: not *always*. If what you want is "everything but X", I don't see why not. The complement of this regex, for example, would get needlessly complicated. Just make sure you actually want "*everything* but..." (future @Raymond: yeah, just noticed. I have trouble reading ---Perl---a bunch of punctuation characters in non-monospace fonts ;)

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: The backslash character that I listed with all the other 'banned' characters <>:\/|?*

Comment: When working with Regex strings in C#, it helps immensely to use a __verbatim__ string literal - `Regex regex = new Regex(@"...");`

Comment: @Jaymz: Nitpick: `"a"` is a string literal too. `@"a"` is a verbatim string literal.

Comment: @Martinho, apologies, rushed typing - you're right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do a double escape. Try this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("TIM[1-9]|BIN[1-9]|[<>:\\\\\"/|?*]");
```

Explanation:

You need to escape the backslash in C# strings to get a backslash in the string. Additionally, the string needs to have two backslashes, because Regex also requires the backslashes to be escaped.

BTW, using verbatim strings makes it a bit more readable:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"TIM[1-9]|BIN[1-9]|[<>:\\""/|?*]");
```

Both codes will result in a Regex with this expression:

```
TIM[1-9]|BIN[1-9]|[<>:\\"/|?*]
```